# How can I tell if my interface{} is a pointer?

Tags: go

If I have an interface being passed into a function, is there a way to tell if the item passed in is a struct or a pointer to a struct?  I wrote this silly test to illustrate what I need to figure out.

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Value string
}

func TestInterfaceIsOrIsntPointer(t *testing.T) {
    var myStruct interface{} = MyStruct{Value: "hello1"}
    var myPointerToStruct interface{} = &MyStruct{Value: "hello1"}
    // the IsPointer method doesn't exist on interface, but I need something like this
    if myStruct.IsPointer() || !myPointerToStruct.IsPointer() { 
        t.Fatal("expected myStruct to not be pointer and myPointerToStruct to be a pointer")
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to know this?

Comment: I wanted to know more about the underlying type contained in the interface because the encoding/json package that I am using to decode json data doesn't work if you pass it a struct rather than a pointer to a struct.  I have a method that allows you to provide a URL and a struct and it'll download data from the web, Unmarshal the json and return the struct.  To make it easier to use, I wanted to be able to error if the developer passed in a pointer rather than just a struct instead of just returning empty data

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
func isStruct(i interface{}) bool {
    return reflect.ValueOf(i).Type().Kind() == reflect.Struct
}
```

You can test via changing type according to your needs such as `reflect.Ptr`. You can even get pointed value with `reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(i))` after you ensured it's a pointer.

Addition:

It seems `reflect.Value` has a `Kind` method so `reflect.ValueOf(i).Kind()` is enough.

Comment: [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) has a [`Kind()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Kind) method, so it is enough to just write `reflect.ValueOf(i).Kind()`.

Comment: This answer does not even compile. The correct code is :
 `func isStruct(i interface{}) bool { return reflect.ValueOf(i).Kind() == reflect.Struct }`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the reflect package:

```
i := 42
j := &i
kindOfJ := reflect.ValueOf(j).Kind()

fmt.Print(kindOfJ == reflect.Ptr)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the "real" type of the interface, you can simply use a [`type switch`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch):

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Value string
}

func TestInterfaceIsOrIsntPointer(t *testing.T) {
    var myStruct interface{} = MyStruct{Value: "hello1"}
    var myPointerToStruct interface{} = &MyStruct{Value: "hello1"}
    // the IsPointer method doesn't exist on interface, but I need something like this
    switch myStruct.(type) {
       case MyStruct:
           // ok
           break
       case *MyStruct:
           // error here
           break
    }
    switch myPointerToStruct.(type) {
       case MyStruct:
           // error here
           break
       case *MyStruct:
           // ok
           break
    }
}
```

The code is longer but at least you don't need to use the `reflect` package.